# HTML pages aren't extending from other HTML files

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying (for the first time on my own) to use VSCode to build a web app.  Just starting with the basics, an index.html page with "Hello, world!" on it.  I've also created a layout.html file with code for a navigation bar and some other stuff I got from Bootstrap's sample template as a starting point.

If I open the layout.html file in my browser, the nav bar appears.  But the index.html page doesn't receive this, even though I've put {% extends "layout.html" %} in Index.  It also shows other HTML that's in Layout, but it shows it in plain text.  I'm assuming I'm supposed to have done something to link these files or something?  But I'm not sure what.  Forgive the super noob question but would really appreciate the help.  Including the current code for Layout and Index as well as screenshots of each.

EDIT: For some additional context, I've just finished the CS50 course so my knowledge is limited to what I've learned there. In building web apps in that course, they had set up the server and I guess whatever connections are necessary, we just had to build the pages and the Python code for the app. I've taken a look at their code to compare to mine and I don't THINK I'm missing anything code-wise. So I'm assuming there just is something on the backend I haven't done? I hoped that as long as they were in the same directory they'd see each other I guess?  I've tried running flask in a virtual environment because I thought maybe that was necessary to connect everything, but still no luck.  If you need more clarification on anything I'm happy to provide. I absolutely understand this probably comes off as a ridiculous question but I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days and no luck.

Layout:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Dynamic page title -->
    <title>DemoSend - {& block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- Nav bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <!-- Main body code -->
    <main class="container p-5">
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<p>Hello world!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Layout screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So what technology are you using to put the pages together? PHP, ColdFusion, Angular, Vue, React ?

Comment: Don't know how to use them at this point.  For some additional context, I've just finished the CS50 course so my knowledge is limited to what I've learned there.  In building web apps in that course, they had set up the server and I guess whatever connections are necessary, we just had to build the pages and the Python code for the app. I've taken a look at their code to compare to mine and I don't THINK I'm missing anything code-wise. So I'm assuming there just is something on the backend I haven't done?  I hoped that as long as they were in the same directory they'd see each other I guess?

Answer (score 2):

these {% block content %} is django command i guess if you would like to use them you have to know something about basic of how to make web page by django you can search for how to use template or form and create views in django tutorial ! i am sorry if i am wrong .

Comment: Ah!  The instructors of the course never mentioned Django, the way it was presented it was implied that it was part of HTML or CSS, not another resource/language.  That gives me a good starting point for figuring this out.  Thank you!